# Where can I find ntohl

Tags: c, winapi, header

I'm looking for a header file on windows that I can use to get the ntohl function in C, but Winsock2.h will not work for me. Does anybody know what other header files would provide this?

Here are some errors I get when I try to include Winsock2.h

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PellesC\Include\Win\Winsock2.h(1045): error #2120: Redeclaration of 'getservbyport', previously declared at C:\Program Files (x86)\PellesC\Include\Win\winsock.h(468); expected 'PSERVENT __stdcall function(int, const char *)' but found 'struct servent * __stdcall function(int, const char *)'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\PellesC\Include\Win\Winsock2.h(135): error #2123: Redefinition of 'hostent', previously defined at C:\Program Files (x86)\PellesC\Include\Win\winsock.h(91).
C:\Program Files (x86)\PellesC\Include\Win\ws2def.h(39): error #1050: Redefinition of macro 'AF_IPX'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\PellesC\Include\Win\Winsock2.h(1310): error #2121: Redeclaration of 'LPSOCKADDR_IN'.
```

Comment: Why won't winsock2.h work for you?

Comment: I posted some examples of the errors I get when I try to include it.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to include both `winsock.h` and `winsock2.h`. Does that sound plausible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem eventually. I had neglected to download the windows software development kit and add the include directories etc. in my project. I had assumed that my compiler came with all of the libraries and headers for sockets.

Answer (score 6):

It's *in* `winsock2.h` as per [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and, from a development system of mine (in `C:\Program files (x86) Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\Winsock2.h`):

```
WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE u_long WSAAPI ntohl (__in u_long netlong);
```

I'm not sure why that's "not working" for you. If you're getting an error message, you need to post it.

---

Based on your question edits on why you're having trouble with `winsock2.h`, it appears you're trying to include both `winsock.h` and `winsock2.h` - that's rarely a good idea :-) They're actually fundamentally incompatible, `winsock2` is a later version with extra goodies.

Unfortunately, it's not always under your obvious control since `windows.h` automagically include `winsock.h` for you under most circumstances.

From memory, one way around this is to define `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before including `windows.h`. This will prevent some of the lesser-used headers from being included.

Another is to define `_WINSOCKAPI_` before including `windows.h` - this will prevent `winsock.h` from being included as well.

The third (and prbably preferable) way is simply to include `winsock2.h` *before* `windows.h`. `winsock2.h` defines `_WINSOCKAPI_` so has the same effect as the previous paragraph.

Comment: Winsock2.h has never worked for me. I get a mess of errors whenever I try to include it. I will post some examples in my original post.